# Is my code correct?

Tags: html, css

I need to do a card for showing some data. I had some problems with the blue left box on the left side, and to add custom paddings. It think I can add padding with a more simple way, but I don't know how. I don't want to use nth-child because it's not supported on old IE. I want an opinion about my code :

**html**

```
<table class="card">
<tr class="padding-top">
    <th class="blue">text</th>
    <th class="padding-left">text</th>
    <th>text</th>
    <td class="button-cell" rowspan="4">
        <a class="button" href="#">text</a>
        <a class="button" href="#">text</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="last blue" rowspan="6">text</td>
    <td class="padding-left">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="padding-top">
    <th class="padding-left padding-top">text</th>
    <th class="padding-top">text</th>
</tr>
<tr class="padding-bottom">
    <td class="padding-left">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="padding-left" colspan="3"><hr/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="padding-top">
    <th class="padding-left" colspan="3">text</th>
</tr>
<tr class="padding-bottom">
    <td class="padding-left" colspan="3">
        Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet organa mandalore mon hutt 
        solo ackbar leia darth qui-gonn ponda. Moff gamorrean
        calrissian ben maul ackbar skywalker ventress. Darth
        wicket dagobah calrissian mon organa chewbacca binks
        darth. K-3po palpatine organa ackbar utapau wookiee
        secura hutt. Darth ackbar baba mothma biggs ahsoka
        kenobi windu. Greedo k-3po calrissian c-3p0 solo
       calrissian jango darth. Fett dooku moff dooku
       jade grievous leia organa antilles. Ahsoka darth
        hoth padmé padmé. Antilles chewbacca fisto 
        darth dagobah dagobah yavin fett.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
 table.card {
        border-spacing: 0; 
        border: 1px solid #C9C9C9; 
        border-radius: 3px; 
        margin-bottom: 20px; 
        width: 984px; 
        background-color: #FAFAFA; 
        color: #060606; 
        table-layout: fixed; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
    } 

    table.card:last-child { 
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    table.card tbody.expand .hidden { 
        display: none; 
    } 

    table.card tbody.collapse .hidden { 
        display: table-row; 
    } 

    table.card th.small-column { 
        width: 180px; 
    } 

    table.card th { 
        padding: 0; 
        text-align: left; 
        color: #007CB7; 
    } 

    table.card td { 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        word-wrap: break-word; 
    } 

    table.card .blue { 
        padding: 0 2px; 
        width: 50px; 
        background-color: #007CB7; 
        color: #FAFAFA; 
        text-align: center; 
        vertical-align: top; 
    } 

    table.card th.blue { 
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 0; 
    } 

    table.card td.last.blue { 
        border-radius: 0 0 0 3px; 
    } 

    table.card td.button-cell { 
        width: 110px; 
        vertical-align: middle; 
    } 

    table.card td.button-cell > a.button:last-child { 
        margin-top: 10px; 
    } 

    table.card td.button-cell > a.button { 
        display: block; 
    } 

    table.card .padding-left { 
        padding-left: 20px; 
    } 

    table.card tr.padding-top > td, 
    table.card tr.padding-top > th { 
        padding-top: 10px; 
    } 

    table.card tr.padding-bottom > td, 
    table.card tr.padding-bottom > th { 
        padding-bottom: 10px; 
    }
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is difficult to review (see BCdotWEBs comment), but here are some general remarks:

HTML elements and CSS classes are supposed to represent the structure of the data you are displaying. You are obviously using the table for layout not for the structure of the data.

- Use `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc. for titles and headlines, use `<ul>` for lists of things, use `<table>` for tabular data.
- CSS classes should describe the kind of data in the HTML, not how it looks or its layout.

I'll show an example how it could/should be, but since you haven't described what kind of data you are displaying and are using dummy text instead of real content, this is just off the top of my head:

```
<section class="book"> <!-- This data represents a book for this example -->
  <h2>Title of the book <span>Subtitle of th book</span></h2>
  <dl>
    <dt>Author</dt>
    <dd>Some Guy</dd>
    <dt>Publisher</dt>
    <dd>Some one else</dd>
    <dt>Year</dt>
    <dd>1999</dd>
    <dt>ISBN</dt>
    <dd>XXXXXXXXXXX</dd>
  </dl>
  <ul class="buttons">
    <li><a href="">Read</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="summary">
    <h3>Summary</h3>
    <p>
      Lorum ipsum...
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Then you can use CSS to style it like you did in your design.

---

Avoid fixed (pixel) sizes in your CSS. In the current web with countless mobile devices with countless different screen sizes it's insane to attempt a pixel perfect layout.

---

And two final remarks:

- `nth-child` doesn't seem to be useful here.
- Really make sure you need to support older browsers (< IE 10). If this is a commercial task plan with enough time/money. Properly supporting IE 8 (or even IE 6) can easily double the time (and thus money) needed.